# Javascript can't access global variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a global variable called `calculated_price`, that holds the price of a selected product. I change the value of this global variable with a function, and then with another function I submit it to a server with an AJAX post request:

```
var calculated_price;

function calculatePrice() {
    calculated_price = $$( '.myInput' ).val();
    $$( '.price-holder' ).text( calculated_price );
}

function submitOrder( calculated_price ) {
    if( calculated_price !== null || calculated_price !== '' ) {

        $$.post( 'http://www.example.com/payment.php', { price: calculated_price}, 
        function( data ) {

            alert( 'Data: ' + data );

        });

    }
}
```

I'm using Framework7, so the JS framework I use is Dom7, however this is very similar to jQuery and the $$.post function I'm using always worked so far. It just can't seem to access the `calculated_price variable`. I've not redeclared this variable anywhere in my code (nowhere have I put `var` in front of it except for when it's declared globally). Any idea why this variable gets lost until the last function is executed (submitOrder)? I know the variable exists and has value, because in the `calculatePrice` function I put the calculated price inside an HTML element and it does show the price correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by can't access? You get an error? What line throws the error? Etc.

Comment: You've got an issue with `if( calculated_price !== null || calculated_price !== '' )`: that should be `if( calculated_price !== null && calculated_price !== '' )`

Comment: @Utkanos There's no error, otherwise I had fixed it already. It just returns nothing. I alert the calculated_price inside the submitOrder function and it's just completely empty. No error or anything.

Comment: Not what you're asking, not the problem, but note that the variable would never be `null`, at least, not in the code shown where it starts out as `undefined` but then gets assigned to a string. The `!==null` test should be `!==undefined`.

Comment: @AndréDion You misunderstood me, I just said that if I had an error I would have fixed it, because errors mostly tell you exactly what's wrong ;) It's just that this particular issue produced no errors.

Comment: Do you not imagine that there are thousands of questions on SO where the OP has failed to look in the console, or has but has failed to report this information in the question? And it's far from obvious that, if you did see an error, you'd have managed to resolve it. Mine was a perfectly reasonable question. Check your frustration; we're here to help.

Comment: @Utkanos I didn't say it was an unreasonable question. I just didn't know so many people on SO ask questions without checking their console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring `calculated_price` globally, and then you use the same name as a function parameter.

```
var calculated_price;

function submitOrder( calculated_price ) { <---- error is here
```

Those are 2 different variables. When you call submitOrder, do you send calculated_price as a parameter?

Comment: those are 2 different variables. 
When you call submitOrder, do you send calculated_price as a parameter?

Comment: Ahhh, I see now. I've changed the name of the function parameter variable and now it works. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine except for the line

```
if( calculated_price !== null || calculated_price !== '' ) {
```

You probably meant to say

```
if( calculated_price !== null && calculated_price !== '' ) {
```

Because of that, when the function `submitOrder` is called, the ajax request will be performed, even if `calculated_price` is undefined.

Comment: It doesn't. But I am suspecting that the function `submitOrder` is called before `calculated_price` is initialized and then test in the conditional is true and a wrong ajax request goes ot. Then the OP thinks it is because of a global variable issue. I think it is a valid theory.